# Getting specific lines of data from a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, email

I use Mailkit and it has a function that fetch me email body text `GetMessage().Textbody`
, i want to get specific lines of email body that contain specific strings

For example:

```
12313 banana milkshake
12356 choco milkshake
kiwi milkshake 1231313
```

***and goes on....***

I want to get from the 700 lines of email text body only 2 lines that contains the word "kiwi" and "choco"

```
   Using reader As New StreamReader("mail.txt")
                While Not reader.EndOfStream
                    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
                    If line.Contains("kiwi" or "choco") Then
                        Console.WriteLine(line)
                        Exit While
                    End If
                End While
            End Using
```

i've been trying to find a better and faster way instead of saving string to file then using this

Comment: does TextBody return one string or an array of lines (as strings).

Comment: why is this tagged C# ?

Comment: you are aware that this is not valid right `line.Contains("kiwi" or "choco") `??

Comment: @pm100 return one string with /n for new lines so it's one string output multiple lines

Comment: @pm100 yea i know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `or` inside the function call like that; you need two separate `Contains()` calls. Also, this can be **way** shorter:

```vb
Dim lines = File.ReadLines("mail.txt").
            Where(Function(line) line.Contains("kiwi") OrElse line.Contains("choco"))

For Each line As String In lines
    Console.WriteLine(line)
Next
```

But that still assumes the `mail.txt` file. Given a string like `Textbody` we can write this function:

```vb
Public Iterator Function GetLines(input As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim line As String = Nothing
    Using rdr As New StringReader(input) ' Not StreamReader!
        line = rdr.ReadLine()
        While line IsNot Nothing
            Yield line
            line = rdr.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Using
End Function
```

And then use it to replace the `File.ReadLines()` in my original sample like so:

```vb
Dim lines = GetLines(GetMessage().Textbody).
            Where(Function(line) line.Contains("kiwi") OrElse line.Contains("choco"))

For Each line As String In lines
    Console.WriteLine(line)
Next
```

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/fh1G4H

If you start to add more search terms, where all of the `OrElse` expressions become tedious, you can do this:

```vb
Dim toSearch() As String = {"kiwi", "choco"}    
Dim lines = GetLines(GetMessage().Textbody).
            Where(Function(line) toSearch.Any(Function(key) line.Contains(key)))

For Each line As String In lines
    Console.WriteLine(line)
Next
```

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/AROhWQ

Comment: thank you for your time , but i get this error System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.String] vb.net

Answer (score 0):

in c# since I dont know vb.net but you can translate

```
string msg = GetMessage().TextBody();
var lines = msg.Split('\n');
var res = lines.Where(l=>(l.Contains("kiwi") || l.Contains("choco")));
```

if the linq stuff doesnt translate well to vb.net then do

```
var res = new List<string>();
foreach(var l in lines)
{
    if (l.Contains("kiwi") || l.Contains("choco"))
    {
         res.Add(l);
    }
}
```